# wp_editor in front end not working

Tags: uploads, wp-editor

This has been asked earlier [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119412/wp-editor-doesnt-work-in-front-end-area), but the answers did not help me. I followed the WP Codex but I still don't see the TinyMCE icons. While I don't care for the icons, I would like the users to have the media upload functionality.

The Add Media button is visible but does nothing when clicked.

I am logged in as 'Admin' and here's what I have on the page:

```
$settings = array( 
    'media_buttons' => true,
    'dfw' => true,
    'textarea_name' => 'vceditor',
    "drag_drop_upload" => true
);  
$editor_id = "vceditor";
$content = 'Start';
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

I have added `wp_enqueue_media();` in my the functions file too.

What am I missing?

P.S: the WP version is 4.3.1

Answer (score 3):

Silly mistake, my custom page was missing the

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: this save my day, thank you